# laravel model relation for nested models

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables in a laravel project, namely:
-center
-payments
-payment_details

center table:
[image]

payment table:
[image]

payment_details table:
[image]

now i want to select all data from payment_details table,i got it it displayed well, but there is a search option for payment_type for the list,But the search filed is not in payment-details table , so i don't know how to retrieve that fro m another table

Comment: Please can you show the models relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are modeling your data with Eloquent relationships Do somthing like:

```php
$type = 'c'; // For example
PaymentDetail::whereHas('payment', function ($query) use ($type) {
   $query->where('type', $type);
})->get();
```

If not you had to do join statement with payments table